# RenderContents vs. RenderChildren

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the difference between [RenderContents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.rendercontents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [RenderChildren](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.renderchildren%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ? They seem to do the same thing - render what's between the opening and closing tag of a custom Control.

Comment: Is one used to output the `content`, the other to allow it's children to output their `content`?